# sendfile() completion to non-blocking socket

Tags: c, sockets, nonblocking

In my program, I need to check the completion of a sendfile() operation in a non-blocking socket. How can that be done?

After checking the documentation and searching on internet, I couldn't find out how to do it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works very similarly to `send()`: if the socket is set as `O_NONBLOCK` and the operation would block, `sendfile()` returns immediately and sets `errno` to `EAGAIN`. In this case you have to wait a while and then try again (maybe using a function like `select()` to know when it's ready).

Also keep in mind that even if it succeeds it may not write all the bytes you requested in a single function call. Always check the return value:

> If the transfer was successful, the number of bytes written to out_fd is
>   returned.  On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately.

You can also take a look at the [man page for sendfile()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sendfile.2.html)

Comment: To expand slightly: if `sendfile()` returns a value > 0, then that many bytes have now been successfully sent - there's no need to wait for completion.  "Non-blocking" does not imply "asychronous".

Comment: Just to confirm: select() will report the socket as writtable (FD_ISSET()==true) when the current block has been flushed.  You then need to call sendfile() again, but keep a new offset.

Comment: @caf: What happens when the *input* file descriptor blocks?

Comment: @KerrekSB: In most cases the point is moot, because the input file descriptor will be a disk file, which cannot block.  The only other case would be using a block or character device node which supports both `mmap` and blocking operation, which would be a very unusual combination (and it's unusual to `sendfile()` directly from a device node at all).  In such a case though, I believe `sendfile()` would wait for the input data, just as if the process had mapped the device and taken a minor fault on the mapping.

Comment: @caf: I understand that you can now have both file descriptors be sockets, so I was thinking of a neat'n'cheap echo server implementation. But never mind the reasons, I just can't find any documentation for the precise behaviour of `sendfile` when none, one or both of the FDs are non-blocking. Whose edge is triggered?

Comment: @KerrekSB: What OS? I don't believe that is the case on Linux right now.

Comment: @caf: I saw this [here (Linux)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendfile.2.html): "`out_fd` [...] can be any file".

Comment: @KerrekSB: Sure, but `in_fd` is the one with the restriction.  If you want to make an "echo" server where the data doesn't go through userspace, you can use `splice()` to splice from input socket to a pipe, then from the pipe to an output socket.

Comment: @caf: Hm, I think `in_fd` *never* had any restrictions. It could be anything, and it could sensibly be non-blocking, non?

Comment: @KerrekSB: The same man page you linked to says *"The `in_fd` argument must correspond to a file which supports `mmap(2)`-like operations (i.e., it cannot be a socket)."*